# After cleaning application data, one user object is still left at Room database

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-room

I have thw following methods in my MainActivity -

```java
private ArrayList<User> usersList;
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fetchUserList();
  }

  private void fetchUserList() {
    userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);
    final Observer<List<User>> userObserver = users -> {
      usersList = (ArrayList) users;
      initViewsAndListeners();
      addCards();
    };
    userViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(this, userObserver);
  }
```

The issue I am facing is that when I go to the app settings and clean my app data, it leaves one (the last) user of the array in the memory, and for some reasons the callback is being called twice instead of once. That means that after the app data is being cleaned, I get one more iteration of `addCards()` method, and cards that should not be added are being added. Why would this happen? isn't cleaning application data kills everything? why would it leave one item at the array?

By the way, my Room DB is adding now 3 hard coded User objects.

edit -

here is my `addCards()` method -

```java
@Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    int buttonTag = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(view.getTag()));
    TinderCardView topCardOnStack = tinderStackLayout.getTopCardOnStack();
    topCardOnStack.handleButtonPressed(buttonTag);
  }
```

Comment: The data is saved to disk not memory, so clearing memory will not clear data from the SQlite database for which ROOM is a wrapper. If you installed the App or cleared the App's data then you would lose the data (assuming that your are using the standard location for the database).

Comment: @MikeT Alright, so I mistakenly written app memory and not app data. What I ment was cleaning the app data, which is what I did, and I was left with 1 item only when re-entering the app, and for some reason the observer re-entered the observe function and added 1 card 1 time (the one that was left in data) and 3 more cards (the hard coded users that are in my room library)

Comment: What is the use of addCards() method?

Comment: @AmitTiwary adding child views (custom frame layout classes) as a child to another view displaying them all as cards. Will add the code

Comment: @AlonShlider You have provided some onClick method code. is this the right code?